# MongoDB index going stale

Tags: mongodb, indexing, query-performance

Using mongo server v3.6.16.

I have a mongo collection with about 18m records. Records are being added at about 100k a day. I have a query that runs fairly often on the collection that depends on two values - `user_id` and `server_time_stamp`. I have a compound index set up for those two fields.

The index is regularly getting stale - and queries are taking minutes to complete and causing the server to burn all the CPU it can grab. As soon as I regenerate the index, queries happen quickly. But then a day or two later, the index is stale again. (ed. the index is failing more quickly now - within 30 mins.)  I have no idea why the index is going stale - what can I look for?

---

Edit

Here are the index Fields:

```
{ 
   "uid" : 1, 
   "server_time_stamp" : -1
}
```

and index options:

```
{ 
    "v" : 2, 
    "name" : "server_time_stamp_1_uid_1", 
    "ns" : "sefaria.user_history"
}
```

This appears to be a Heisenbug.  When I used "explain", it performs well.  Here is one of the pathological queries, from the long query log, taking 445 seconds:

```
sefaria.user_history command: find { find: "user_history", filter: { server_time_stamp: { $gt: 1577918252 }, uid: 80588 }, sort: { _id: 1 }, lsid: { id: UUID("4936fb55-8514-4442-b852-306686985126") }, $db: "sefaria", $readPreference: { mode: "primaryPreferred" } } planSummary: IXSCAN { _id: 1 } keysExamined:17286277 docsExamined:17286277 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:142780 nreturned:79 reslen:35375 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 285562 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 142781 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 142781 } } } protocol:op_msg 445101ms
```

Here's the results of `explain` for a performant query, right after regenerating the index:

```
{ 
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : NumberInt(1), 
        "namespace" : "sefaria.user_history", 
        "indexFilterSet" : false, 
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "uid" : {
                        "$eq" : 80588.0
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "server_time_stamp" : {
                        "$gt" : 1577918252.0
                    }
                }
            ]
        }, 
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH", 
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN", 
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "uid" : NumberInt(1), 
                    "server_time_stamp" : NumberInt(-1)
                }, 
                "indexName" : "server_time_stamp_1_uid_1", 
                "isMultiKey" : false, 
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "uid" : [

                    ], 
                    "server_time_stamp" : [

                    ]
                }, 
                "isUnique" : false, 
                "isSparse" : false, 
                "isPartial" : false, 
                "indexVersion" : NumberInt(2), 
                "direction" : "forward", 
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "uid" : [
                        "[80588.0, 80588.0]"
                    ], 
                    "server_time_stamp" : [
                        "[inf.0, 1577918252.0)"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }, 
        "rejectedPlans" : [
            {
                "stage" : "FETCH", 
                "filter" : {
                    "server_time_stamp" : {
                        "$gt" : 1577918252.0
                    }
                }, 
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN", 
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "uid" : NumberInt(1), 
                        "book" : NumberInt(1), 
                        "last_place" : NumberInt(1)
                    }, 
                    "indexName" : "uid_1_book_1_last_place_1", 
                    "isMultiKey" : false, 
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "uid" : [

                        ], 
                        "book" : [

                        ], 
                        "last_place" : [

                        ]
                    }, 
                    "isUnique" : false, 
                    "isSparse" : false, 
                    "isPartial" : false, 
                    "indexVersion" : NumberInt(2), 
                    "direction" : "forward", 
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "uid" : [
                            "[80588.0, 80588.0]"
                        ], 
                        "book" : [
                            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                        ], 
                        "last_place" : [
                            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }, 
            {
                "stage" : "FETCH", 
                "filter" : {
                    "server_time_stamp" : {
                        "$gt" : 1577918252.0
                    }
                }, 
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN", 
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "uid" : NumberInt(1)
                    }, 
                    "indexName" : "uid", 
                    "isMultiKey" : false, 
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "uid" : [

                        ]
                    }, 
                    "isUnique" : false, 
                    "isSparse" : false, 
                    "isPartial" : false, 
                    "indexVersion" : NumberInt(2), 
                    "direction" : "forward", 
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "uid" : [
                            "[80588.0, 80588.0]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }, 
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true, 
        "nReturned" : NumberInt(97), 
        "executionTimeMillis" : NumberInt(1), 
        "totalKeysExamined" : NumberInt(97), 
        "totalDocsExamined" : NumberInt(97), 
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH", 
            "nReturned" : NumberInt(97), 
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberInt(0), 
            "works" : NumberInt(99), 
            "advanced" : NumberInt(97), 
            "needTime" : NumberInt(0), 
            "needYield" : NumberInt(0), 
            "saveState" : NumberInt(3), 
            "restoreState" : NumberInt(3), 
            "isEOF" : NumberInt(1), 
            "invalidates" : NumberInt(0), 
            "docsExamined" : NumberInt(97), 
            "alreadyHasObj" : NumberInt(0), 
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN", 
                "nReturned" : NumberInt(97), 
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberInt(0), 
                "works" : NumberInt(98), 
                "advanced" : NumberInt(97), 
                "needTime" : NumberInt(0), 
                "needYield" : NumberInt(0), 
                "saveState" : NumberInt(3), 
                "restoreState" : NumberInt(3), 
                "isEOF" : NumberInt(1), 
                "invalidates" : NumberInt(0), 
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "uid" : NumberInt(1), 
                    "server_time_stamp" : NumberInt(-1)
                }, 
                "indexName" : "server_time_stamp_1_uid_1", 
                "isMultiKey" : false, 
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "uid" : [

                    ], 
                    "server_time_stamp" : [

                    ]
                }, 
                "isUnique" : false, 
                "isSparse" : false, 
                "isPartial" : false, 
                "indexVersion" : NumberInt(2), 
                "direction" : "forward", 
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "uid" : [
                        "[80588.0, 80588.0]"
                    ], 
                    "server_time_stamp" : [
                        "[inf.0, 1577918252.0)"
                    ]
                }, 
                "keysExamined" : NumberInt(97), 
                "seeks" : NumberInt(1), 
                "dupsTested" : NumberInt(0), 
                "dupsDropped" : NumberInt(0), 
                "seenInvalidated" : NumberInt(0)
            }
        }
    }, 
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "mongo-deployment-5cf4f4fff6-dz84r", 
        "port" : NumberInt(27017), 
        "version" : "3.6.15", 
        "gitVersion" : "18934fb5c814e87895c5e38ae1515dd6cb4c00f7"
    }, 
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

Comment: Please post the following details: (i) the query, (ii) the index definition and the (iii) query plan generated using `explain` with `executionStats` mode.

Comment: Added what I could, now.  I'll aim to get an `explain` when it next misbehaves.

Comment: I suggest you generate a query plan one _now_ (when running okay) and one when it _misbehaves_ (so that we can compare).

Comment: Added the results of explain for a working query, right after index regeneration.

Comment: On a flow of 100K docs a day & having 17m docs could be quiet a bit high for index creation,It is quiet common -queries run slower during index creation cause of high cpu utilization,I believe executionStats may not help you in this issue(As it will only let you know whether query picks an index/not but in your case queries are faster during non index times).May be you can increase your disk size+ram & also from your query since you've index on timestamp,if you're only querying for recent docs(just in case) then split the collection maybe just migrate old data,Or you can shard your collection.

Comment: @Laizer : What do you mean by index getting stale ? Queries not able to use index ? And what do you mean by regenerating index ?

Comment: Queries are scanning all 17m records, as shown in the pathological example above.   By regenerating, I mean dropping and recreating the index.

Comment: The query  plan's "executionStats" says _"totalKeysExamined" : NumberInt(97)_. The query filter is using index defined on the collection ("stage" : "IXSCAN") and the compound  index "server_time_stamp_1_uid_1" is used. Also, the query's sort is also using the index (the index on `_id`). As it is the query and the indexes are working as they are meant to be.

Comment: And, _"executionTimeMillis" : NumberInt(1)_ says that it is a performant query.

Comment: @prasad_ the `explain` is for a performant query.  The one above, which took 445s was the same query executed during a pathological phase.

Comment: I'm afraid that my experiment in giving the instance more memory didn't help.  Even with 20GB of overhead free, it's still doing the same things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was about a query that runs well and uses the indexes suddenly stops using the index and results in a very poor performance. This is noted in the *query plan* and the *log* respectively.

*The explain's output:*

The query plan's "executionStats" says `"totalKeysExamined" : NumberInt(97)`. The query filter is using index defined on the collection ("stage" : "IXSCAN") and the compound index "server_time_stamp_1_uid_1" is used. Also, the query's sort is using the index (the index on `_id`). As it is the query and the indexes are working as they are meant to be.  And, `"executionTimeMillis" : NumberInt(1`) says that it is a performant query.

*Details from the log:*

```
{ ... 
find: "user_history", filter: { server_time_stamp: { $gt: 1577918252 }, uid: 80588 }, sort: { _id: 1 }
planSummary: IXSCAN { _id: 1 } keysExamined:17286277 docsExamined:17286277  numYields:142780 nreturned:79 
... }
```

From the log, note that the index "server_time_stamp_1_uid_1" is *not* used.

*Discussion:*

The data and the index (called as [working set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-working-set)) for the frequently used queries are kept in the memory (RAM + file system cache). If the working set is not in the memory the system has to load it into the memory during the operation and it results in a slower performance. Reading from disk drive is much slower than the memory. Note that SSD drives are much faster than the HDD drives and when there is no option to increase the memory this could be an option.

Also, if the query is using indexes and the index size is large and could not be in memory, the index has to be read from the disk drive and it will slow down the operation. More memory is a solution and when not possible the solution can be in redesigning (or re-modeling) the data and its indexes.

But, the the problem in this case was not the available memory; there is enough of it.

The following info gives an idea about how much memory might be used for the working set for a given query:
`db.collection.stats().indexSizes`, `size`, `count` and `avgObjSize`.

**Solution:**

The query log with slow performance shows that the index "server_time_stamp_1_uid_1" is not used: `planSummary: IXSCAN { _id: 1 }`.

One way to make sure and force the query to use the index (always) is to use the [hint](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/index.html) on the query. The `hint` need to be on the index "server_time_stamp_1_uid_1". This way the situation as seen in the log will not happen.

Another way is to keep the index active in the memory. This can be achieved by running a query on the indexed fields only (a covered query: the query filter and returned fields are of indexed fields only). Running this *dummy* query, which runs often *or* before the actual query will make sure the index is available in the memory.

In this case, as @Laizer mentioned that supplying the `hint` to the query helped resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is due to the index not being capable of being selective *and* servicing the sort.

The log line for the slow operation is showing the operation using the `_id` index. The query planner likely made this selection to avoid having to sort results in memory (note the lack of [`hasSortStage: 1`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-profiler/#system.profile.hasSortStage)). As a consequence, however, it required scanning considerably more documents in memory (`docsExamined:17286277`) which made it take considerably longer.

Memory contention likely also played a part. Depending on load, the overhead from sorting results in memory may have contributed to pushing the index out of RAM and the _id index being selected.

A few comments:

1. As Babu [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59559370/1092767), the explain posted above does not include a sort. Including the sort would likely show that stage consuming more time than the IXSCAN.
2. The name for the index (`server_time_stamp_1_uid_1`) suggests that `server_time_stamp` is placed first in the index, followed by `uid`. Equality matches should be prioritized; i.e. `uid` should be [placed before ranges](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-and-non-prefix-subset-of-an-index).

Some options to consider:

- Create the index `{ "uid" : 1, "_id" : 1, "server_time_stamp" : 1 }`. See [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-on-multiple-fields) for guidance on sorting using indexes. Results may be mixed though given that both `_id` and `server_time_stamp` are likely to have a high cardinality, which means you may still be trading off scanning documents for avoiding a sort.
- Assuming that the `_id` values are auto-generated, consider sorting by `server_time_stamp` rather than `_id`. This will allow you to bound AND sort using `server_time_stamp_1_uid_1`. The `server_time_stamp` is a timestamp, so it will also be relatively unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
sefaria.user_history command: find { find: "user_history", filter: { server_time_stamp: { $gt: 1577918252 }, uid: 80588 }, sort: { _id: 1 }, lsid: { id: UUID("4936fb55-8514-4442-b852-306686985126") }, $db: "sefaria", $readPreference: { mode: "primaryPreferred" } } planSummary: IXSCAN { _id: 1 } keysExamined:17286277 docsExamined:17286277 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:142780 nreturned:79 reslen:35375 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 285562 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 142781 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 142781 } } } protocol:op_msg 445101ms
```

Looking at the query plan, the query uses _id index.  Is it because you have a sort of _id field. I looked at your other plan attached.

```
"executionSuccess" : true, 
"nReturned" : NumberInt(97), 
"executionTimeMillis" : NumberInt(1), 
"totalKeysExamined" : NumberInt(97), 
"totalDocsExamined" : NumberInt(97),
```

The number of documents returned / examined are 1:1 ratio.

Also the query is using

```
"indexName" : "server_time_stamp_1_uid_1", 
"isMultiKey" : false, 
"multiKeyPaths" : {
    "uid" : [
    ], 
    "server_time_stamp" : [
    ]
},
```

I think there is something is missing in both queries. May be the sort is not mentioned in the good plan. Can you please check.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue here was memory.  The instance was operating near the limit of physical memory.  I can't say for sure, but I believe that the relevant index was being removed from memory, and that the poor query performance was a result of that.  Regenerating the index forced it back into memory (assumedly, something else got kicked out of memory.)

I've put the instance on node with much more memory, and so far it seems to be performing well.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm trying to insist !! explain has nothing to do with this, maybe you can use more ram or shard your collection !!

Comment: The data and the index for the frequently used applications (called as Working Set) are kept in the memory (RAM + file system cache). If the working set is not in the memory the system has to load it into the memory during the operation and it is a slower performance. Also, if the query is using indexes and the index size is large and could not be in memory, the index has to be read from the disk drive and it will slow down the operation. More memory is a solution and when not possible the solution can be in redesigning (or re-modeling) the data and its indexes.

Comment: I had thought this worked, but it only held out for a couple days.  Now I have the same dynamic recurring, even with 20GB of unused memory on a 60GB instance.

Comment: Please post the info from these: `db.collection.stats().indexSizes`, `db.collection.stats().size`, `db.collection.stats().count` and
`db.collection.stats.avgObjSize`. Also, what other queries are running on this collection?

Comment: The query log with slow performance shows that the index "server_time_stamp_1_uid_1" is _not used_: `planSummary: IXSCAN { _id: 1 }`. Here are couple of points: (1) One way to make sure / force the query to use the index (always) is to use the _hint_ on the query. The `hint` need to be on the index "server_time_stamp_1_uid_1".

Comment: (2) Create a _dummy query_ which 
will use the index "server_time_stamp_1_uid_1" and runs quickly; e.g., `db.collection.find( { server_time_stamp: 1577918252 }, uid: 80588 }`, where the `uid` value has very few documents. Run this dummy query before the actual one, everytime you run the actual query (and see if it helps).

Comment: @prasad_ your suggestion to use `hint` seems to be the gamer winner here.  Can you make it an official answer so that I can give you a bounty?